# How to trigger .fail handlers from promise .then handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

**tl;dr** what can I do within a function that is part of a `.then()` chain to immediately trigger any `.fail()` handlers? (Using jQuery 1.9.1)

Long version:

I have a bunch of tests and and test-prep tasks to perform, but some are expensive, so I wish to perform them all sequentially. I wrote this:

```
$.when( gatherEasyData() )            // collect into for test #1
 .then( failIfDataBad )               // test #1

 .then( makeRestCall )                // fetch info for test #2
 .then( extractRestPayload )          // prepare info for test #2
 .then( failIfPayload1Unacceptable )  // test #2, based on REST info

 .then( makeHarderRestCall )          // fetch info for test #3
 .then( extractRestPayload )          // prepare info for test #3
 .then( failIfPayload2Unacceptable )  // test #3, based on expensive REST info

 .then( action1 )                     // success case!

 .fail( action2) ;                    // failure case :(
```

The idea is that if any test fails, or any of the test-prep work fails, I want to skip the more expensive tasks and jump right to the fail handler.

Also, by relying on `then` to chain these guys together, none of the actual functions need to be promise-aware; they can focus on whatever contract is appropriate for their task, and they can pass data down the line as needed. E.g.: `failIfDataBad` (AKA Test #1) will receive a deep hash of config that was created by `gatherEasyData`, and the function only needs to inspect the hash and `return` its verdict. So, every function on the list returns data or a boolean.

I've discovered that none of my failure cases actual trigger the `.fail`. The REST calls are made using `$.ajax`, and when those come back with HTTP error codes, `action 2` ***is*** invoked instead of `action 1`. But none of my custom tests seem capable of short-circuiting the resulting steps.

My question: what must I do within `failIfDataBad` to cause execution to skip to the `.fail` handler at the bottom?

Consider that this is the current implementation of `failIfDataBad`:

```
function failIfDataBad(data) {
    if(!data) return false; // should trigger .fail
    if(data.prop1 === true) return false; // should trigger .fail

    if(data.prop2 > 500) return false; // should trigger .fail


    return true; // should permit next .then
}
```

I have tried (without success):

- `throw`
- `return false`
- not returning

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is return a rejected promise.

All of your steps should be returning promises if they're doing any asynchronous actions.

```
var success1 = function () {
    return $.Deferred(function (d){ return d.resolve();}).promise();
};
var success2 = function () {return $.Deferred(function (d){ return d.resolve();}).promise();};
var success3 = function () {return $.Deferred(function (d){ return d.resolve();}).promise();};
var fail = function () {
    return $.Deferred(function (d){ return d.reject();}).promise();
};
var success4 = function () {return $.Deferred(function (d){ return d.resolve();}).promise();};

success1()
    .then(success2)
    .then(success3)
    .then(fail)
    .then(success4)
    .done(function() {
        console.log("Successful. :(");
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log("Failure. :)"); // this one happens
    });
```

`success1-4` are simply returning resolved promises while `fail` returns a rejected promise.

http://jsfiddle.net/43Mr8/

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying this now, but I want to object on the grounds that if `$.when` can accept promises, sync function calls, and scalars, and silently wrap them in promises, I'd expect `.then` to do the same. A promise lib will be more useful if it can consume and organize code that is not promise-aware. I'm going to hold out for a better answer, for now.

Comment: that's one of many problems with the jQuery promise api. However, since it is so widely used, it's unlikely to be "fixed" any time soon. With most promise apis simply using throw and having a catch at the end would be enough to break the chain, however that isn't the case for jQuery promises.

Comment: Agreed. So, I think you're saying: a better promise lib would allow me to write "dumb" functions that aren't promise-aware, and then stitch them together into chains that also include async tasks without having to make them smarter, but jQuery isn't that lib, i.e. jQuery cannot do what I'm asking for. Is that right?

Comment: correct. The native Promise api might be more suitable, if you can find a good polyfil for browsers that don't support it.

Comment: success2 and 3 could return nothing and not change the behavior, fyi

Comment: Marking as the answer. It's too bad jQuery's promise implementation doesn't support such a reasonable use-case.